# jQuery Custom Validator in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

I am trying to implement a custom validator in an input-text-field to validate that there are no blankspaces in the string using the [jQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). The validation should be vailable as attribute in the `input` tag. I am adding following method to the jquery validator:

```
$.validator.addMethod("nospaces", function (value, element) {
        return new RegExp("^\\S\*\$").test(value);
    },
    "No blankspaces allowed."
);
```

I am trying to access this `nospaces` method in the `input` tag like the `required` validation in most examples:

```html
<input id="myInput"
     name="myInput"
     type="text"
     class="form-control"
     nospaces>
```

This is not working, neither when I am adding `nospaces=""`. But when I add an arbitrarily string like `nospaces="xx"` it works.

I don't want to add this arbitrarily string which isn't really needed. But I don't know how to reach it.

Comment: Probably because there is no such thing as a `nospaces` HTML attribute.   You invented it.  However, you can just as easily put it inside with your classes instead.